# Adding Custom Columns to DataFrame via a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

Essentially, I want whatever variable is input into the function to be added to the title of the new column - adding to the string.

I have a dataframe with many columns and am trying to add new columns, which takes inputs of other other columns, and am doing so by a function. However, I am having trouble naming these new columns that are added - I want them to be named based off the inputs that are given in the function. I have attached a photo to show what I am talking about. 
in: RSI(x)
outcolumnname: 'xRSI' where x changes based on the input give in the function

[image: Code and dataframe showing what I am trying to do]

Comment: It looks like `x` is just a number, so name the column `f'{x}RSI'`

Comment: worked. thank you much